# Converting this nested loop method to a Stream Lambda function

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, jackson, java-stream

Given the following method with a nested `for` loop:

```
private Set<PlanningItem> getPlanningItems(Set<JsonNode> nodes) {
    Set<PlanningItem> planningItems = new HashSet<>();
    for (JsonNode node : nodes) {
      for (JsonNode planningItem : node.findPath(PLANNING_ITEMS.getValue())) {
        planningItems.add(new PlanningItem(planningItem));
      }
    }     
    return planningItems;
  }
```

I have converted it into a nested `forEach` method like so:

```
private Set<PlanningItem> getPlanningItems(Set<JsonNode> nodes) {
    Set<PlanningItem> planningItems = new HashSet<>();
    nodes.forEach(node -> node.findPath(PLANNING_ITEMS.getValue()).forEach(planningItem -> planningItems.add(new PlanningItem(planningItem))));
    return planningItems;
}
```

I'm curious if this can be done using nested streams or if that's even optimal given this simple structure and the fact that we're working with a `JsonNode` collection without a built in stream method.

Comment: `map` function is the way to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a flatmap, this will turn a stream of streams of X to a stream of x.

When using streams, map and flatmap are your friends for

Also for things that don’t have a stream() method on them but are iterable you can do this

```
StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
```

e.g.

```
nodes.stream() //stream of JsonNode objects
    .flatMap(node -> StreamSupport.stream(node.findPath(PLANNING_ITEMS.getValue()).spliterator(), false)) //stream of JsonNode from the node.findPath
    .map(planningItem-> new PlanningItem(planningItem)) //converts node to PlanningItem
    .collect(Collectors.toSet()); //collects to a set
```

Comment: The OP has already mentioned, "we're working with a JsonNode collection without a built in stream method.", so not sure if this will compile for them.

Comment: doesnt set have stream on it? but at the very least if its iterable you should be able to do something like this to get the stream `StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);`

Comment: "doesnt set have stream on it", I am referring to `node.findpath(PLANNING_ITEMS.getValue()).stream()` not `nodes.stream()`

Comment: node.findpath(PLANNING_ITEMS.getValue()) is iterable but does not contain a stream method. Can you edit your question to include that StreamSupport.stream and also fix the `flatMap` and `findPath` casing so I can accept it?

Comment: @daniel9x I have made the change

Comment: Thanks @Ash. Hate to nitpick, but the `flatMap` and `findPath` casing are still off.

Comment: @daniel9x no worries, fixed it up, sadly the browser isnt an IDE/complier and pick up my errors